# JPEG containing multiple DHT marker

Tags: jpeg, image-compression, libjpeg

I have a JPEG file that contains more than one DHT marker. Is it allowed according to specification?
If it is allowed, then which DHT marker should I use to define huffman table?

Comment: Yes, the standard allows multiple DHT markers and/or multiple DHT tables within one marker.

Comment: @MarkSetchell So which one should I choose? 
Also, if one of them is corrupt, should I return error or I should ignore the corrupt one?

Comment: I'm not sure, it's not really my area. I believe they are normally merged together,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the definition of the DHT marker. It starts with a length for the marker. This is followed by 4-bit fields that identifies whether the table is an AC or DC table and a numeric identifier for the table. That is followed by the number of symbols in the table and then the symbols.

If you read the symbols and have not used up the length, you loop and read the next table in the same format. It is more common to put all the tables in one DHT marker but the choice is up to the encoder.

The Start of Frame marker maps the component to the Huffman table by number. Pick the tables specified by the SOF marker. For a color image, you could have to use as many as 6 Huffman tables to decode.

If the table is corrupt, the stream is corrupt and you are SOL.

Comment: one of the DHT marker contains nothing (contains just marker but no table etc). Should I just ignore this?

Comment: You mean the length is zero? If so, I guess you could ignore it.